# Responsive text does not work properly with fittext.js and jquery fadeIn

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/) to make text responsive and and i have 3 divs which become visible when the corresponding link is clicked. The divs are contained h2 tags. the issue is,  The text does not show up when i use fade in effect. Please help me

HTML

```
<a id="one" href="#">one</a>
<a id="two" href="#">two</a>
<a id="three" href="#">three</a>

<div class="one content">
    <h2>one</h2>
</div>
<div class="two content">
    <h2>two</h2>
</div>
<div class="three content">
     <h2>three</h2>
</div>
```

css

```
.content {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.content {
    display: none;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("a").click(function() {
        var cls = $(this).attr('id')
        $(".content").fadeOut(100);
        $('.' + cls).delay(100).fadeIn(400);
        return false;
    });


jQuery("h2").fitText();
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g76G9/)

Comment: The css FAQ section suggest: that it is mandatory to have h1{display:block;}
https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Comment: Here's the explanation: When you have .content {display: none;}. The fitText cannot apply the js onload, since the element is hidden. There might be a work around, but I am not sure at this point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out i came up with a solution by using jquey. i added font size as an inline style,  before the element fadein and then i removed that style after the div fade in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the explanation: When you have .content {display: none;}. The fitText cannot apply the js onload, since the element is hidden. There might be a work around, but I am not sure at this point. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is h2{font-size:0}...gets added from somewhere.

Here's what you can do:

```
.content {
   background: red;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 10px;
   font-size:60px;
   width: 84%;
   max-width:500px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g76G9/4/

Comment: If i do this The text is no longer responsive and no point of using fittext.js

Comment: Well you should use "em" instead of pixels to make it responsive. I am not sure how fittext works.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But there is an issue. I need this text to be at least about 80px large in large devices and when the browser  become smaller text should become smaller responding to the browser width. So if i set min width as 60 or 80 ow whatever value it does not reduce the font-size less than that. Basically Fittext.js is use to show big headers in smaller devices. Please excuse my bad Englsih

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle which uses opacity instead of display:none which has the same effect that it has now but with fitText working correctly!

http://jsfiddle.net/g76G9/16/

```
<a id="one" href="#">one</a>
<a id="two" href="#">two</a>
<a id="three" href="#">three</a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="one content">
        <h2>one</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="two content">
        <h2>two</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="three content">
         <h2>three</h2>
    </div>
</div>

.content {
    background: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.container{
    margin: 10px;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    opacity:0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}

$("a").click(function() {
        var cls = $(this).attr('id')
        $(".content").css('opacity', '0');
        $('.' + cls).css('opacity', '1');

        return false;
    });


  jQuery("h2").fitText();
```